# How to detect if shift key is down on action

Tags: javascript, ember.js, keyboard-events

In my Ember app, I would like to detect if the shift key is being held down when a photo is clicked

> ...{{action "selectImage" photo}}...

As far as I can tell, it is not possible to get an event from an action. Any ideas on how to get around this problem?

**A little more info**

In my action I would like to to know if shift is being held down. eg.

```
actions: {
    selectImage (photo) {

        if (shiftIsDown) {
            ...
        }
        ...
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a custom component for your photo and override the click event.

```
click: function(e) {  
  if(e.shiftKey) {
    this.send('selectImage');
  }else{
    // do nothing
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah makes sense! Will try this out

Comment: made a twiddle with this implemented as a test, can probably try putting that directly into a component, if you only need it once. Or try using a mixin to help out a bit. [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/675dc01200589af087769496ca697aa0?openFiles=components.test-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.test-component.hbs)

Answer (score 0):

In Ember 3.9 I ended up with this:

```
<div onclick={{action "foo" bar}}>
```

Specifying the action this way causes foo() to be called with two arguments: the bound value of bar as the first argument, and the event object as the second argument. You can inspect the event object to find out what modifier keys were pressed during the click.